# Text inside a text box and adjustable

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to create a flexible text box. Where I can do the following:

- Adjust the size of the text box
- Insert text inside a text box and choose the fonts etx...

Where can I start? Which programming languages do I need to use? HTML? Javascript?
What software is best to use for this type of work?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Form tag from html and input Tag and get the text from the textbox with a document.getElementById('idOfDiv').value or if you want you can use jQuery lib for all the js utils you might need further.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a text editor (like Word) checkout the following:

**CKEDITOR:** https://ckeditor.com/

**TinyMCE:** https://www.tiny.cloud/

Answer (score 0):

CSS will perfectly solve this task. using Span, Padding, border, font-size, font-weight, font-type, etc.

You can also use Javascript to solve this but HTML and CSS is the best way to get around it

Regards